# mouse click isn't registered immediately after keyboard interaction

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a custom checkbox. I have handled click and onkeypress for space key. It works fine, but if i try to click on it just after a space key is pressed, the mouse click isn't registered.

for example, this series of events:

- click -> checked
- click --> uncheked
- onkeypress -> checked
- onkeypress-> uncheked
- click -> isn't registered
- click -> checked

it isn't like the first click isn't registered, it is not registered only when i click too soon after space key press.

I checked it with the default html checkbox as well, and it has the same problem.

I am not specifically looking for a solution as this scenario would not happen practically, but rather the cause.
Anyone know a reason for this?
It seems like the onkeypress event handler does not immediately return and so main thread is blocked and does not capture any interactions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am testing this in Chrome v71 on Windows.

Comment: It works fine for me in the snippet above, i can't reproduce your problem. (I'm also puzzled that you don't appear to have any code to handle the event of pressing the space bar, yet it still works, and only with that key. Is this a browser default thing?)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Text shows after `space -> click`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, browser handles spacebar key as a click when `input type='checkbox` is focused. Also works for `<button>` for `submit` event etc.

Comment: @ritaj i am sorry there is no other way to ask this but are you clicking fast enough?

Comment: Yeah, I click immediately after unchecking with spacebar.

Comment: in that case maybe it is not a browser limitation. i would check on another laptop to see if it is the same

Comment: i can't also reproduce the behavior. at first, there were some situations that checkbox did not changed its state when press it quickly after mouse click.. but i then realize that it was due to not pressing the keyboard well down (the space bar is not sensitive enough...). May be your mouse click button has some issues which cause you think so...

Comment: I am able to replicate the issue. However I am not aware of the reason for this behaviour. As you have mentioned, I think it is due to the delay in return from event handler.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan yeah, i initially thought so, but then i made sure that i press the click button hard enough. That doesn't seem to be the issue. I tested with other applications (slack, skype, etc) and it seems to recreate the same behaviour, which leads me to think this issue is probably from the OS or hardware.